# How to delete all nodes of a given content type programmatically?

Tags: nodes

Sometimes for testing purpose we need to delete a lot of nodes of a given content type, in this case the use of the web interface (YOUR_SITE/admin/content) is not the best option.

How to delete all nodes of a given content type programmatically?